# ExtJS Combobox displaying some weird spaces

Tags: extjs, combobox, yii, margins

I'm getting some weird spaces displaying in my combobox. I've already replaced the ExtJS library in my project and still no luck.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Here's a pic of how it looks...

[image]

And here's the code I used

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.AddMaintenanceWindow',{
extend      :'Ext.window.Window',
constructor :function(config){
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [
    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
]
});
    Ext.apply(this,{
        title   :'Agregar nueva entrada de mantenimiento',
        items   :[
                    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
                        items       :[
                                        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                                            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
                                            store: states,
                                            queryMode: 'local',
                                            displayField: 'name',
                                            valueField: 'abbr'
                                        })
                                    ]
                    })
                ]
    });
    this.superclass.constructor.call(this);
},
initComponent:function(){
    this.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
})
```

Just in case...I'm using Yii + ExtJS (without Ext4Yii)

By the way I also tried to use boxselect (I downloaded it and copied it) and got the same result but with a boxselect)

I solved this by creating a new yii project and copying all the files to that project. Wierdly enough I had already done that before and it didn't work, but this time it did. I'm still curious about what the problem could have been though.

Comment: I am quite sure your problem cannot be solved with this snipped. You either have some CSS parts that overrides the ExtJS CSS or you have done a ExtJS update without updating the CSS.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is I've replaced the extjs library folder and even started a new project and it didn't work... I'm guessing it has something to do with a css from yii since it works like a charm if its just a php + extjs project. But I don't know where to look for that css

Comment: Use the chrome developer tools.  For each element, it will show you where the applied styles are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the screenshot it looks like you are getting some extra `padding` or `margins` in the list (not spaces). Use a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox with Firebug to inspect the elements around "Alabama". Find which CSS selector is adding the extra padding/margin and override it for your listbox.

Comment: it doesn't seem to have any padding... here's what the inspector showed....

<div id="boundlist-1054" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default" tabindex="-1" style="left: 814px; top: 301px; height: auto; z-index: 29001; width: 192px;">
<div id="boundlist-1054-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Alabama</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Alaska</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Arizona</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

Comment: also, notice the "padding" between the field and the dropdown arrow... I guess it's got something to do with the css used for it, but I didn't change any of them

Comment: You will need to see the CSS properties (not just inline styles). I am ready to inspect it if the code in question is somewhere online.

Comment: It isn't online, and it won't ever be.. I just used the ExtJS stylesheets though.. dunno how could have gone wrong

Comment: Do you want help via TeamViewer? I m free for around 20mins.

Comment: I didn't see this but sure, if you ever have some free time again I could use that